# Python inconsistent behaviour in terms of referencing by comparing 2 simple examples

Tags: python, reference

I have 2 examples below:

Example 1:

```
simplelist = [0] * 2
for i in range(2):
    simplelist[i] = i
print(simplelist)
```

result: `[0, 1]`

Example 2:

```
listinlist = [[0]] * 2
for i in range(2):
    listinlist[i][0] = i
print(listinlist)
```

result: `[[1], [1]]`

As you can see, in the 1st example, the two 0s appear not related to each other, and the code works as expected. However, when I replace the 0s with [0]s in example 2, the two [0]s appear related as if they are referenced to the same object. I think when I assign values to each of them, I assign values to the same object twice, so the second  value 1 overwrites the first value 0. Please correct me if I am wrong and help me understand this issue. If you think it is not a referencing issue, please also share your opinion.

Comment: In the second example, `listinlist` contains two references to one single list. It doesn't hold two separate lists. Or in other words, `*` doesn't copy the object, it copies the reference to the object.

Comment: This isn't inconsistent at all. In *both* cases, `[x]*2` creates a *new list* with two references to the object inside, i.e. `x`. In one case, that object is an `int`, in the other it is a list. In the second case, you *mutate* that object. In the first case, you don't, you simply assign another value at that index. You'd see the same behavior in the second case if you did something *equivalent*, like `listinlist[i] = [i]`